# group by postgres in every id like

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, postgresql-9.3

Can someone help me to solved my issue , i have 2 table

Query for table one :

```
  SELECT (REPLACE(A .coano, '0', '')) coano_for_like FROM glfcoa_dump A WHERE posum = 'K' ORDER BY A .coano ASC;
```

Result for table one :

```
coano_for_like 
----------------
1
11
12
13
131
132
2
21
211
212
22
221
2211
292
2921
2922
2923
2924
293
```

Query for table two :

```
SELECT
    coano,
    SUM (CAST(endbal AS NUMERIC)) endbal
FROM
    vw_fx_glfmas
WHERE
    OFCID = '450'
AND TGL = '2017-08-11' and coano like '11%'
GROUP BY 
    coano
ORDER BY
    SUBSTRING (coano ,- 2, 7) ASC
```

Result For table two :

```
coano   endbal
--------------
111000  0
112000  234342846
114000  0
```

in table two `coano like '11%'` 11 is result from table one

my question , how to **group by all coano like in table two**  from result table one ?

**i want result like this :**

```
coano_for_like  coano   endbal
----------------------------------
1               111000  0
                112000  234342846
                114000  0
                152101  813307251
                152102  49259791
                162110  -3456957
                163010  0
                169100  -36826000
                169200  -32649000
11              111000  0
                112000  234342846
                114000  0
12              ...     ...
```

Comment: Much better, if you post your sample data (and desired output also) as formatted text, not images

Comment: please review again my question ...thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like in a join.

```
SELECT coano_for_like, coano, SUM (CAST(endbal AS NUMERIC)) endbal
  FROM vw_fx_glfmas 
  JOIN (SELECT (REPLACE(A .coano, '0', '')) coano_for_like FROM glfcoa_dump A WHERE posum = 'K') r
 WHERE OFCID = '450' AND TGL = '2017-08-11' and coano like coano_for_like || '%'
 GROUP BY coano
 ORDER BY coano ASC
```

**slightly correcting**

```
SELECT
    r.coano_for_like,
    coano,
    SUM (CAST(endbal AS NUMERIC)) endbal
FROM
    vw_fx_glfmas a,
    (
        SELECT
            (REPLACE(A .coano, '0', '')) coano_for_like
        FROM
            glfcoa_dump A
        WHERE
            posum = 'K'
    ) r
WHERE
    ofcid = '450'
AND TGL = '2017-08-11'
AND coano LIKE coano_for_like || '%'
GROUP BY
    coano_for_like,
    a.coano
ORDER BY
    coano_for_like ASC
```

Comment: this great query ... Thank you guys for help me :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to change your GROUP BY and SELECT in the second query to group by the REPLACE function you've used in query 1:

```
SELECT
a.coano_for_like,
b.coano,
SUM (CAST(b.endbal AS NUMERIC)) AS endbal
FROM 
  (SELECT REPLACE(coano, '0', '') AS coano_for_like
  FROM  glfcoa_dump) AS a
INNER JOIN vw_fx_glfmas b ON a.coano_for_like = b.coano
WHERE b.ofcid = '450'
AND b.tgl = '2017-08-11'
AND b.posum = 'K'
GROUP BY a.coano_for_like,
b.coano
ORDER BY A.coano ASC;
```

Does this give you the result you need?

Comment: I've tried using group by,but the result not like i want. Inner join combining the same coloumn, i want  coloumn "coano_for_like  " combining  with coano (vw_fx_glfmas) without eliminate the coano(vw_fx_glfmas). not coano (glfcoa_dump) combine  coano (vw_fx_glfmas).

Comment: I've updated the join to use coano_for_like as you mentioned. Is this what you need? I've also used a subquery to better represent the REPLACE function.